# SolrCloud in production - querying q=* gives numFound=0

Tags: solr, solrcloud

So I have a three-node cluster deployed using a zookeeper. And successfully created `test` collection (3 shards). Then after I have

`curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'ec2FirstNodeIP:8983/solr/test/update' --data-binary ' [ { "f1" : "1", "f2" : "2", "f3" : "3" } ]'`

I got 
`{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":38} ...`

However when I have `curl "sameIP:8983/solr/test/select?wt=json&indent=true&q=*:*"`

I am getting 
`NumFound:0`

But using the admin UI for updating the document, the query now returns the document
[image for admin UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd7Og.png)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make document searchable we should commit. use commit=true

`ec2FirstNodeIP:8983/solr/test/update?commit=true` this should work.

Comment: It worked! I didn't have to add any `commit=true` in the localhost version. Can you please describe what happened? if you can give a documentation link talking about this that would be great.

Comment: check the section on Commits. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/UpdateHandlers+in+SolrConfig  Your solr instance probably had a default auto commit / softcommit . And your document showed up after that time passed.

Comment: Did you restart solr ?, if yes. solr will call autocommit.  to make every document searchable we have to commit after indexing it. After you restarted it will call autocommit which is configured in solrconfig.xml so it worked.

Comment: @jay no document showed even after a long time without specifying commit=true. I wonder why

Comment: @vinod Yes I restarted solr to work on SolrCloud mode and I took the same config files for the -cloud option. I am accepting this answer and also I would appreciate if you we can find out why when working on a real distributed environment the commit behavior changes.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. it doesn't mean it worked because you restarted solr in cloud mode. commit remains same. I mean either in standalone or cloud mode we have to commit after any changes(indexing, deletion of doc etc) to reflect.

Comment: I mean the behavior was totally different when launching with -cloud but on local host. I never had to commit

Comment: @vinod let me know if you have any thoughts please